# Google Play Saved Games - Huge amount of conflicts

Tags: android, google-play-games

I'm currently running into a problem where my app generates a **huge** amount of conflicts. I can't figure out what is causing these conflicts to occur. As long as I use the app on only one device it seems to be going fine, but every so often it just keeps coming up with conflicts.

I use the following code to open snapshots. I call `openSnapshot` for both reading and writing snapshots.

```
private Pair<Boolean, Snapshot> openSnapshot(GoogleApiClient googleApiClient) {
    Snapshots.OpenSnapshotResult result = Games.Snapshots.open(googleApiClient, "save", true).await();
    return processSnapshotResult(result, googleApiClient);
}

private Pair<Boolean,Snapshot> processSnapshotResult(Snapshots.OpenSnapshotResult result, GoogleApiClient googleApiClient) {
    final int statusCode = result.getStatus().getStatusCode();
    if (statusCode == GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_SNAPSHOT_CONFLICT) {
        Log.d("Snapshot", "Snapshot conflict detected.");
        final String conflictId = result.getConflictId();
        final Snapshot conflictingSnapshot = result.getConflictingSnapshot();
        final Snapshot snapshot = result.getSnapshot();

        try {
            final SnapshotContents snapshotContents = snapshot.getSnapshotContents();
            if (snapshotContents != null) {
                final byte[] readFully = snapshotContents.readFully();
                database.mergeWith(activity, SavedInstance.this, readFully,false);
                Log.d("Snapshot", "Merged 1");
            } else {
                Log.d("Snapshot", "Merge 1 was null");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            final SnapshotContents snapshotContents = conflictingSnapshot.getSnapshotContents();
            if (snapshotContents != null) {
                final byte[] readFully = snapshotContents.readFully();
                database.mergeWith(activity, SavedInstance.this, readFully,false);
                Log.d("Snapshot", "Merged 2");
            } else {
                Log.d("Snapshot", "Merge 2 was null");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.d("Snapshot", "Resolving " + conflictId);
        /*Snapshot newSnapshot = */Games.Snapshots.resolveConflict(
                googleApiClient, conflictId, snapshot).await().getSnapshot();

        Log.d("Snapshot", "Resolved " + conflictId);
        return new Pair<>(true,openSnapshot(googleApiClient).second);
    } else if (statusCode == GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_SNAPSHOT_CONTENTS_UNAVAILABLE) {
        return new Pair<>(false,result.getSnapshot());
    } else if (statusCode == GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK) {
        return new Pair<>(false,result.getSnapshot());
    } else {
        return new Pair<>(null,null);
    }
}
```

An example logcat of such a merge would be:

```
07-20 21:36:22.715 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:36:22.772 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:36:22.811 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:36:22.811 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESLTFZS1JvNURjTHhZbzJRcC1acDcxQjJoaEY3WHRlTlB3Rk1lUFF4bFBVS0w3TRikcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:36:26.609 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolved DriveId:CAESLTFZS1JvNURjTHhZbzJRcC1acDcxQjJoaEY3WHRlTlB3Rk1lUFF4bFBVS0w3TRikcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:36:29.056 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:36:29.118 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:36:29.169 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:36:29.169 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESLTFrWVlXcDY3WHVDbm5icTh0OG5CNmhjZm5WZUJZX3N1TTAyTlZpOUdULTFLZhimcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:36:33.027 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolved DriveId:CAESLTFrWVlXcDY3WHVDbm5icTh0OG5CNmhjZm5WZUJZX3N1TTAyTlZpOUdULTFLZhimcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:36:36.620 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:36:36.709 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:36:36.751 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:36:36.751 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESLTFtMFlHRzBCMFZiandZeTdxZmdaWVlSYmNObk5yU1poODQ3dzloRTNYX2lZThiocSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:36:46.469 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolved DriveId:CAESLTFtMFlHRzBCMFZiandZeTdxZmdaWVlSYmNObk5yU1poODQ3dzloRTNYX2lZThiocSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:36:48.500 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:36:48.587 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:36:48.635 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:36:48.635 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESLTFPbm5ob0U3U0UxeGpJNURrOXNJVGVNWGpCYkgzSFBtZjlMd1JkaFg4Y2pweBiqcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:36:52.392 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolved DriveId:CAESLTFPbm5ob0U3U0UxeGpJNURrOXNJVGVNWGpCYkgzSFBtZjlMd1JkaFg4Y2pweBiqcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:36:54.221 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:36:54.330 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:36:54.364 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:36:54.364 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESLTFzQVE1RDg5VGl2cUJ2dlNIdERUR1FuWUY4d0dvZFo2Q0lValRzaUxYNzVWZRiscSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:36:58.538 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolved DriveId:CAESLTFzQVE1RDg5VGl2cUJ2dlNIdERUR1FuWUY4d0dvZFo2Q0lValRzaUxYNzVWZRiscSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:37:00.864 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:37:00.928 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:37:00.990 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:37:00.990 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESLTFMUWZQSWtzTWRCbFpYUG5Ic0pWdWtyNTVwczhaX1lZVWpMSmFBMzBZV2ZScxiucSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:37:05.785 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolved DriveId:CAESLTFMUWZQSWtzTWRCbFpYUG5Ic0pWdWtyNTVwczhaX1lZVWpMSmFBMzBZV2ZScxiucSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:37:07.622 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:37:07.766 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:37:07.798 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:37:07.798 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESLTEtdGl1LUxja2w0bzRKVGxmQy16dG5tSGZIVGRuZlpJNFB2bUswM3UtS3JpaRiwcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:37:11.619 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolved DriveId:CAESLTEtdGl1LUxja2w0bzRKVGxmQy16dG5tSGZIVGRuZlpJNFB2bUswM3UtS3JpaRiwcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:37:13.655 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:37:13.740 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:37:13.788 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:37:13.788 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESLTF6YTNWYWw0ZWs2ekVqcjZHTm1ETExhVktrUGJoX3pnRmdtbnZQN0JPanF0bRiycSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:37:17.934 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolved DriveId:CAESLTF6YTNWYWw0ZWs2ekVqcjZHTm1ETExhVktrUGJoX3pnRmdtbnZQN0JPanF0bRiycSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:37:19.757 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:37:19.832 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:37:19.879 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:37:19.879 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESLTFXNTBQZ2l1YzdQVEdaT1FKRm5sc1NCMTl4V2k1SjRNSlhlcEc1QkNZR0xJXxi0cSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:37:23.952 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolved DriveId:CAESLTFXNTBQZ2l1YzdQVEdaT1FKRm5sc1NCMTl4V2k1SjRNSlhlcEc1QkNZR0xJXxi0cSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:37:26.292 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:37:26.382 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:37:26.439 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:37:26.440 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESLTE4bnBQTjFTQ3J1QmxmZHljMDJlYXZycFdEWkdXeE1BaUk0T2JmbkcwektMQxi2cSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:37:31.311 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolved DriveId:CAESLTE4bnBQTjFTQ3J1QmxmZHljMDJlYXZycFdEWkdXeE1BaUk0T2JmbkcwektMQxi2cSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:37:33.261 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:37:33.351 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:37:33.443 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:37:33.443 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESLTFvcXRzWGY3d3A2dnhHSjVySUZpSEVCdGdXTDZoeGxsajJiQld1X0tOVmRoQhi4cSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:37:37.546 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolved DriveId:CAESLTFvcXRzWGY3d3A2dnhHSjVySUZpSEVCdGdXTDZoeGxsajJiQld1X0tOVmRoQhi4cSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:37:39.506 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:37:39.584 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:37:39.637 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:37:39.637 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESLTFmZzZXMk1hZjZOOWw5S3pveVRtY25jZVpVQ1prSzl5OTg3Skhxal95eWtJYhi6cSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:37:43.472 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolved DriveId:CAESLTFmZzZXMk1hZjZOOWw5S3pveVRtY25jZVpVQ1prSzl5OTg3Skhxal95eWtJYhi6cSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:37:45.807 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:37:45.899 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:37:45.928 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:37:45.928 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESLTFjd0FGNU96cTFETjRFMWdXVVMyZXhsTUl1MlJCU1plMmI1amhKVm5NOGVzThi8cSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:37:49.972 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolved DriveId:CAESLTFjd0FGNU96cTFETjRFMWdXVVMyZXhsTUl1MlJCU1plMmI1amhKVm5NOGVzThi8cSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:37:51.839 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:37:51.914 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:37:51.957 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:37:51.957 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESLTF5ZG96cGJjaGxnaW9qck0wNGFsbnNhMjRmRjFraWZxcE5yZmctTHQ2RkZfaxi-cSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:37:55.896 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolved DriveId:CAESLTF5ZG96cGJjaGxnaW9qck0wNGFsbnNhMjRmRjFraWZxcE5yZmctTHQ2RkZfaxi-cSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:37:57.921 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:37:58.006 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:37:58.165 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:37:58.165 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESLTEtbXNIUU5lNDVPc2RFMW14b0piZjdNdzRyX00wbTBMd3NZRmRudV8yenVtVxjAcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:38:02.247 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolved DriveId:CAESLTEtbXNIUU5lNDVPc2RFMW14b0piZjdNdzRyX00wbTBMd3NZRmRudV8yenVtVxjAcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:38:04.264 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:38:04.388 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:38:04.467 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:38:04.467 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESLTE5dVQ0ZnlDNE5TXzFGdHFKMGhmMUpiYTRDVlZhUTdNR1p3RTdaTTlYd3Z1ehjCcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:38:08.338 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolved DriveId:CAESLTE5dVQ0ZnlDNE5TXzFGdHFKMGhmMUpiYTRDVlZhUTdNR1p3RTdaTTlYd3Z1ehjCcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:38:10.301 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:38:10.393 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:38:10.427 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:38:10.427 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESLTFNVlVHXzhxTWNwVEc0amNKUThDSWxBekRUTkdNQ0FaNHUxaVM4N0pLOGpLMBjEcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:38:14.450 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolved DriveId:CAESLTFNVlVHXzhxTWNwVEc0amNKUThDSWxBekRUTkdNQ0FaNHUxaVM4N0pLOGpLMBjEcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:38:16.434 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:38:16.503 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:38:16.542 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:38:16.542 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESLTE5WmNkWWJJLWRhQ0pWY0NZMW9PaGFpWUdFSDNUWVZlMlVQMkFPWW9wU1N6SxjGcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:38:25.211 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolved DriveId:CAESLTE5WmNkWWJJLWRhQ0pWY0NZMW9PaGFpWUdFSDNUWVZlMlVQMkFPWW9wU1N6SxjGcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:38:27.255 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:38:27.367 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:38:27.420 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:38:27.420 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESLTFydGcyWmZPd1NqdmZUSVdfV0VhWlNTekJmSkwzbjhWRkZIRzlxd0FYdWZnYxjIcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:38:31.506 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolved DriveId:CAESLTFydGcyWmZPd1NqdmZUSVdfV0VhWlNTekJmSkwzbjhWRkZIRzlxd0FYdWZnYxjIcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:38:33.433 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:38:33.509 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:38:33.549 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:38:33.549 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESLTFDQ0hzQmNYd3pwYTZtRm9fRHJDM0dTN3RlNVVxUXBQdTFtc0tNZUpGMmVOQxjKcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:38:37.691 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolved DriveId:CAESLTFDQ0hzQmNYd3pwYTZtRm9fRHJDM0dTN3RlNVVxUXBQdTFtc0tNZUpGMmVOQxjKcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:38:39.666 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:38:39.756 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:38:39.790 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:38:39.790 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESLTE5SXp4cjZzcVlzRXI5V09EZElMdFBIUjFQX0tsREhuVDF2UzhKa2FYWTBQOBjMcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:38:43.772 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolved DriveId:CAESLTE5SXp4cjZzcVlzRXI5V09EZElMdFBIUjFQX0tsREhuVDF2UzhKa2FYWTBQOBjMcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:38:47.238 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:38:47.300 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:38:47.336 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:38:47.336 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESLTFaaEg3NWRKYy14UDlkX0Z1TGhzUzZzSWgtbG5Ed3R3aXE3TVJNVWtzVXZpVhjOcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:38:56.599 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolved DriveId:CAESLTFaaEg3NWRKYy14UDlkX0Z1TGhzUzZzSWgtbG5Ed3R3aXE3TVJNVWtzVXZpVhjOcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:38:58.591 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:38:58.716 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:38:58.755 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:38:58.755 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESLTFsa1VOdnFyX2NDQko0NERVNm1McHIyTTAzcmxIYzluOE1wbkY1WGNPNTc4NBjQcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:39:02.940 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolved DriveId:CAESLTFsa1VOdnFyX2NDQko0NERVNm1McHIyTTAzcmxIYzluOE1wbkY1WGNPNTc4NBjQcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:39:04.906 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:39:04.993 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:39:05.051 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:39:05.051 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESLTFxa0s1TDExbVd5d3QzYkRQVkZuR2dRZ2ZfZmFOLXpQX3NuNTA3ZTRoVl9nehjScSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:39:09.205 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolved DriveId:CAESLTFxa0s1TDExbVd5d3QzYkRQVkZuR2dRZ2ZfZmFOLXpQX3NuNTA3ZTRoVl9nehjScSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:39:11.952 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:39:12.054 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:39:12.115 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:39:12.115 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESLTFBdEEwTEo5M2NhWnhraXRoZktvc085US1zX3VYODRxbG5WTmEzWnFscndoWRjUcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:39:16.008 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolved DriveId:CAESLTFBdEEwTEo5M2NhWnhraXRoZktvc085US1zX3VYODRxbG5WTmEzWnFscndoWRjUcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:39:18.108 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:39:18.179 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:39:18.234 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:39:18.234 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESLTFpcFNrOGtHMEdtWnZueFBkRUh4dHZYUkM5aGlHWklBRXJzYXpGT3BDZ18tZhjWcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:39:22.670 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolved DriveId:CAESLTFpcFNrOGtHMEdtWnZueFBkRUh4dHZYUkM5aGlHWklBRXJzYXpGT3BDZ18tZhjWcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:39:24.393 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:39:24.499 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:39:24.540 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:39:24.540 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESLTFHNWJ5NTA3VXRiME5LcTZ3c05DaHdWek5HSURacmEwTzNlUWw4dENJdUlJSBjYcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:39:28.783 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolved DriveId:CAESLTFHNWJ5NTA3VXRiME5LcTZ3c05DaHdWek5HSURacmEwTzNlUWw4dENJdUlJSBjYcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:39:30.849 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:39:30.927 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:39:30.964 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:39:30.964 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESLTFkd3AxcVpvMUtLTF94Qmp0c2VNQjVCMkhfMUNVTVRTcFRyRGRNSmN1ZVY3MRjacSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:39:35.741 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolved DriveId:CAESLTFkd3AxcVpvMUtLTF94Qmp0c2VNQjVCMkhfMUNVTVRTcFRyRGRNSmN1ZVY3MRjacSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:39:37.702 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:39:37.778 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:39:37.825 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:39:37.825 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESLTFUMXE1NTZId25TeWZ2cTJSUTNoSXhpNEkwa2tydzlBRHpMZmNjQWNrTFRpZBjccSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:39:41.962 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolved DriveId:CAESLTFUMXE1NTZId25TeWZ2cTJSUTNoSXhpNEkwa2tydzlBRHpMZmNjQWNrTFRpZBjccSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:39:44.107 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:39:44.195 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:39:44.259 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:39:44.259 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESLTFZR1gwbzE3LVk1X0RRTEFMY2RYTHVXVkVHRlVCY3hEZnh4Mm9VdXhPOVF3ZBjecSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:39:50.073 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolved DriveId:CAESLTFZR1gwbzE3LVk1X0RRTEFMY2RYTHVXVkVHRlVCY3hEZnh4Mm9VdXhPOVF3ZBjecSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:39:52.307 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:39:52.369 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:39:52.415 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:39:52.415 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESLTEyU3h3QWFGM2ljV3k2a0ZGd3YyVVF0dUJFdnhBYlYzMFF3MFV2a0VSYXRCYRjgcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:39:57.184 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolved DriveId:CAESLTEyU3h3QWFGM2ljV3k2a0ZGd3YyVVF0dUJFdnhBYlYzMFF3MFV2a0VSYXRCYRjgcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:39:59.038 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:39:59.140 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:39:59.181 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:39:59.181 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESLTFhblZqTWhiMjZBYmc3ZXpnX25RYk1jX2FDS083dWlURlI3Q1VlS1kzSk16ahjicSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:40:03.227 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolved DriveId:CAESLTFhblZqTWhiMjZBYmc3ZXpnX25RYk1jX2FDS083dWlURlI3Q1VlS1kzSk16ahjicSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:40:05.538 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:40:05.616 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:40:05.676 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:40:05.676 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESLTFENVNsV2otYmUtUDdhMVY2VXIwblZFZTJBNnZlTW4zSnlTc0J6bE9BTlNHQhjkcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:40:09.397 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolved DriveId:CAESLTFENVNsV2otYmUtUDdhMVY2VXIwblZFZTJBNnZlTW4zSnlTc0J6bE9BTlNHQhjkcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:40:11.347 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:40:11.438 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:40:11.540 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:40:11.540 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESLTFLVmNfaGExRUtNaDVLU2dQYm1IRHRwbmJTRHhldEJ2Wkl2RzdfM1BEMEVUSRjmcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:40:16.440 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolved DriveId:CAESLTFLVmNfaGExRUtNaDVLU2dQYm1IRHRwbmJTRHhldEJ2Wkl2RzdfM1BEMEVUSRjmcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:40:18.483 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:40:18.587 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:40:18.647 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:40:18.647 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESLTFnbU05Qzg5TVhKbmxfUDRGWEMxdWctMGNKb05SNS1BQUttT0drTTdMMnlFaBjocSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:40:22.450 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolved DriveId:CAESLTFnbU05Qzg5TVhKbmxfUDRGWEMxdWctMGNKb05SNS1BQUttT0drTTdMMnlFaBjocSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:40:24.312 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:40:24.395 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:40:24.432 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:40:24.432 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESLTF3X2ZGd2p3eF8yTzljY1FSY2lCTWg1cFBDY1ZZZm1TN2g5TlF6OWgtX2ZWQhjqcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:40:26.594 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolved DriveId:CAESLTF3X2ZGd2p3eF8yTzljY1FSY2lCTWg1cFBDY1ZZZm1TN2g5TlF6OWgtX2ZWQhjqcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:40:27.701 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Conflict detected while reading, calling notifyDataChanged requesting for write.
07-20 21:40:27.728 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Opened snapshot
07-20 21:40:34.682 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:40:34.760 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:40:34.831 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:40:34.831 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESABjscSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:40:37.939 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolved DriveId:CAESABjscSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:40:40.073 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:40:40.157 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:40:40.244 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:40:40.244 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESABjucSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:40:42.449 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolved DriveId:CAESABjucSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:40:50.281 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:40:50.410 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:40:50.451 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:40:50.451 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESLTFSdThyN0w2RzJWOVdYUjU0TVowMlEzb2FpamNQaXVZdF9faWZWLW9EWnNvMBjwcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:40:52.779 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolved DriveId:CAESLTFSdThyN0w2RzJWOVdYUjU0TVowMlEzb2FpamNQaXVZdF9faWZWLW9EWnNvMBjwcSCGutKdtlUoAA==
07-20 21:40:55.561 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Snapshot conflict detected.
07-20 21:40:55.652 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 1
07-20 21:40:55.707 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Merged 2
07-20 21:40:55.707 31065-31161/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Resolving DriveId:CAESABjycSCGutKdtlUoAA==
```

This will generally go on for anywhere from 5 to 30 minutes.

What could be causing this huge amount of conflicts?

(Please let me know if more code is needed.)

Answer (score 0):

In [Handling saved game conflicts](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/savedgames#handling_saved_game_conflicts), your game must decide how to resolve the conflict by picking one of the provided versions or merging the data of the two saved game versions which are the following:

> - The most-up-to-date version known by Google Play games services to be accurate; and
> - A modified version detected on one of the player's devices that contains conflicting content or metadata. This may not be the same as the version that you tried to save.

After detecting saved game conflicts which you have done, you also need to modify a saved game for conflict resolution especially if you want to merge data from the two Saved Games or modify an existing Snapshot to save to the server as the resolved final version. Steps to follow are listed below:

> 1. Pick a `Snapshot` object from `getConflictingSnapshot()` or `getSnapshot()` as your base.
> 2. Next, call `Snapshots.resolveConflict()` and pass in the `Snapshot` that you selected in the previous step. This stores the `Snapshot` to the server.
> 3. Call `open()` to retrieve the `Snapshot` that you just stored in the previous step. Now make your modifications to the returned `Snapshot`, then call `Snapshots.commitAndClose()` to upload the modified save game to the server.

More information and sample snippets can be found in the given documentation.

I hope that helps.